# SQLite with Python "Table has X columns but Y were supplied"

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I have a python script that executes some simple SQL.

```
c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simpletable (id integer PRIMARY KEY, post_body text, post_id text, comment_id text, url text);")
command = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO simpletable VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" % (comments[-1].post_body, comments[-1].post_id, comments[-1].comment_id, 
comments[-1].url)
c.execute(command)
c.commit()
```

But when I execute it, I get an error

> sqlite3.OperationalError: table simpletable has 5 columns but 4 values were supplied

Why is it not automatically filling in the `id` key?

Answer (score 8):

In Python 3.6 I did as shown below and data was inserted successfully.

I used `None` for autoincrementing ID since `Null` was not found.

```
conn.execute("INSERT INTO CAMPAIGNS VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", (None, campaign_name, campaign_username, campaign_password))
```

The ID structure is as follows.

```
ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
```

Comment: +1 for showing an approach using a parameterized query than the formatted string based approach. For e.g., see here about parameterized queries: https://pynative.com/python-sqlite-insert-into-table/

Answer (score 6):

If you don't specify the target columns `VALUES` is expected to provide values for all columns and that you didn't do.

```
INSERT
 OR IGNORE INTO simpletable
                (text,
                 post_id,
                 comment_id,
                 text)
                VALUES ('%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s',
                        '%s');
```

Specifying the target columns is advisable in any case. The query won't break, if, for any reason, the order of the columns in the tables changes.

Answer (score 2):

try to specify the columns names to ensure that the destination of values doesn't depends on order.
ex:

> INTO simpletable
>                (text,
>                  post_id,
>                  comment_id,
>                  text)

And if you wants the id column to be automatically incremented make sure to add Identity property on, or similar auto increment of your dbms.
ex:

> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS simpletable (id integer PRIMARY KEY Identity(1,1),

and remember your script is not prepared to alter the table structure, only creation.

Answer (score 1):

If you wrote code correctly delete your SQL file(`name.db`) and run your code again some time it solve the problem.

Imagine this is your code:

```py
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS food(name TEXT , price TEXT)''')

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO food VALUES ("burger" , "20")')

connection.commit()
```

and you see an error like this:

> table has 1 column but 2 values were supplied

it happened because for example you create a file with one column and then you modify your file to two column but you don't change the file name so compiler do not over write it  because it exist.