# the following error is what I am getting from the code snippet below. sqlite3.OperationalError: table record has 7 columns but 6 values were supplied

Tags: python

```
name, email, contact, gender, country, password = "Rodney", "rodney@gmail.com", "0717405766", "male", "kenya", "12345"

cur.execute("INSERT INTO record VALUES (:name, :email, :contact, :gender, :country, :password)", {
    'name': name,
    'email': email,
    'contact': contact,
    'gender': gender,
    'country': country,
    'password': password

})
```

Comment: However, the code still runs and executes the command in the background.

Comment: Check out: [sqlite3.OperationalError: table book has 6 columns but 5 values were supplied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54198481/sqlite3-operationalerror-table-book-has-6-columns-but-5-values-were-supplied)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLite with Python "Table has X columns but Y were supplied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51643509/sqlite-with-python-table-has-x-columns-but-y-were-supplied)

Answer (score 0):

Your table has 7 columns. You are only specifying values for 6 of them.

If you don't want/need to specify a value for the missing column you should make sure you specify the columns you are inserting values for.

Example:

```
insert into record (name, email, contact, gender, country, password) values (....)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your question. In addition to what TommyN said, below example if you have 7th columns and you want to add data to them, to make sure you understand.

Code below:

```
import sqlite3

con = sqlite3.connect('testingDatabase.sqlite')

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS record(id INT PRIMARY_KEY, name TEXT, 
   email TEXT, contact TEXT, gender TEXT, country TEXT, password TEXT)')

cur.execute('INSERT INTO record(id, name, email, contact, gender, country, 
   password) VALUES(1, "Rodney", "rodney@gmail.com", "0717405766", "male", "kenya", "12345")')

con.commit()
con.close()
```

after that, if you want to see the result use query in execute() method

> SELECT * FROM record;